# Laravel How to register a ServiceProvider within other ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a modular laravel structure which each module have to register their own resources like controllers, views, translations, etc.

And each Module have their own sub modules which they should be able to register their own resources again. It's a tree like structure.

What I need is to register sub modules `ServiceProvider` in modules `ServiceProvider`.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by using `Application::registerDeferredProvider` method.

Here is an example of how this has done:

```
class ModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->registerDeferredProvider(SubModuleServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

Good Luck.